# Secure File Transfer with Individual Control

Tags: encryption

My main goal is to build Raspberry Pi cloud storage and I want to access it remotely. I can easily send commands via SSH.

However, transferring files bugged me due to its slow connection speed, or latency due to buffer, or other factors. I checked SFTP and FTPS for this.

My main goal is to send a file, let's say mixed files of RAWs, JPGs, and MOVs that are about **5 Gigabytes**, and to send it in minimum amount of time. I think this is possible if I **encrypt** the file first on my local machine and **send** it through some connection, then **decrypt** the file once it **reaches there completely**.

What are your suggestions to send large files securely?

Comment: It may seem that your problem is the slow upload speed. I don't think that this is related to our site. [Why when I transfer a file through SFTP, it takes longer than FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8849240/1820553) See the third comment under the question.

Comment: @kelalaka but what is the method for that? Can SFTP commands be used separately, if yes how? Or maybe you can suggest me to use another protocol that I don't know.

Comment: Use plain FTP to send the encrypted data?

Comment: That is a reasonable idea. I still don't know if I can ensure full functionalities of SFTP with this method. However it is enough to get me started. Thank you.

Comment: Please indicate what kind of Raspberry Pi you have and what kind of runtime you are consdiring. Maybe some raspberries contain hardware acceleration for specific algorithms (in the future).

Comment: If the goal is performance, I'm not sure this is a security question either. In general, this looks like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Currently I have a Pi 3B+. I want the pi permanently connected to the internet. Whenever I need to send it some commands, or files I want all of the communication to be encrypted. As you know Pi's CPU is not pretty fast. Thus I don't want to spend the time on decryption on pi or encryption on PC unless those are small files. For the larger files I just want to minimize the time spent on the network. Just think it as this: I shoot some photos and videos in another city. Then I go and use a public internet such as public library internet. Then I leave the place when the upload is done.

Comment: After the upload, I can send a command to Pi to start decryption of the files that are uploaded. I don't care how much time spent on the decryption by Pi. If it takes hours, so it be, because I won't be using the Pi after I leave the library. @kelalaka actually gave a simple method for this but there comes the question of how superior the SFTP over FTP+encryption method is.